# Padblock corrupted exception Android - AES encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am using AES encryption

```
private static final String seed = "This is my secret";

public static String encrypt(String cleartext) {
   try {
       byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
       byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
       return toHex(result);
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted){
   try {
       byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
       byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
       byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
       return new String(result);
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
    return null;
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

The encryption is working fine but I am getting exception on decryption.
The exception occurs at this `byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);`

```
 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:739)
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
```

Comment: Ah, the infamous `getRawKey` function. Good night.

Comment: @ArtjomB Heh, sometimes forget I've got this gold badge :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so where is the answer in the duplicate question?
https://github.com/kruton/android-keyczar-demo is not available anymore

Comment: [Same code .. same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388151/bad-pad-block-exception-when-using-simple-crypto-class)

Comment: Throw away your code and better use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3471/data-encryption-decryption