# How to keep the Seed Value a 'secret'?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

If I am using the following methods to encrypt and decrypt a String...
Shouldn't the seed value be a 'secret' and not 'hard-codded'?
And if so... how would I achieve that goal?

```
String encryption(String userText){
    String seedValue = "SecretKey";
    String userTextEncrypted="";
    try {
        userTextEncrypted = AESHelper.encrypt(seedValue, userText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userTextEncrypted;
}

String decryption(String encryptedText){
    String seedValue = "SecretKey";
    String decryptedText="";
    try {
        decryptedText = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, encryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Below is the AESHelper class...

```
public class AESHelper {

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","Crypto");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

}

Comment: You can issue an HTTP request to the web server (if you have one) and get it from there

Comment: While you are correct that hard coding this value is a bad idea, there isn't enough context here to suggest an alternative.  What is the threat model?

Comment: That depends a lot on what `AESHelper` is doing with it. Is that the key used for encryption? Where does this class come from?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher , I am not using a web server.

Comment: @LukePark , I don't what you mean by threat model.

Comment: I mean, for what reason are you using encryption?  What are you trying to protect, and from who?

Comment: `seedValue` is used like a key, so it should not be hard coded if you want to have any reasonable security. Btw. this `AESHelper` class has also several problems. You should critically review it to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: @LukePark , I'm trying to protect an email address and its password.

Comment: You really need to be more specific.  Client side or server side?  Through transmission or in a database?  Help us to help you!

Comment: @LukePark , lol my bad, its stored with the local database of an Android app using SQLite. The email address and password never leave the device they're stored on.

Comment: You shouldn't store a username and password client side, encrypted or otherwise.  Your design pattern is incorrect.

Comment: @LukePark , Where should I store it ? I was thinking a Firebase DB?

Comment: Is it the users email and password for a service that you do not control?  Or for a service that you do control?  Generally you shouldn't store username and password, you should store a token.  Something like JWT.

Comment: Please don't use `SecureRandom` for password-based key derivation (your seed is generally considered a password). It is considered an anti pattern, because different Android versions have a different implementation of SecureRandom which doesn't have to be seedable meaning, it will generate different key streams even if you use the same seed every time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401421/1816580) for further information why this code is horrible. Why don't you use [tozny/java-aes-crypto](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto)? It has much better defaults.

Comment: @LukePark , Im using an application running Android iOS to store incident reports, and programmatically (without using Intents) email them out. Each client would have a single device at their location, which only the manager and employees should have physical access to. The manager should have a Gmail account dedicated to this application. The email account and its server's properties are used to send out emails to their recipient of choice. 
Its GMail address and its password I would like to keep safe.

Comment: The email and password are stored on the device that does the emailing?  There is no point in encrypting at all, in that scenario.  You should really have a service that sends the emails on behalf of the devices.